# The sequence of operation after apt-get update

Tags: linux, apt, package-management

when typing

```
$apt-get update
```

which one does `apt` checks first :
`sources.list` file or `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory  ?

Answer (score 3):

Let’s see:

```
$ sudo strace apt-get update |& grep -E 'sources\.list|/var/lib/apt/lists' | head
stat("/etc/apt/sources.list", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1515, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/apt/sources.list", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/apt/lists/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
...
```

So it checks `sources.list` first. That makes sense since `sources.list` (and the files in `sources.list.d`) determine the repositories `apt` “knows” about, not the files in `/var/lib/apt/lists`.

Comment: but how does `apt` know the installed packages and their versions on the distribution  before getting their latest versions from repositories

Comment: It knows the installed packages from the `dpkg` status database, `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. It doesn’t know about versions in the distribution before it downloads the repository indexes.